# Under certain conditions, the size of a subset $X$ of a group $G$ is a multiple of another subgroup $Y$ of $G$.

Tags: group-theory

Here is the full text (taken from MA Armstrong's book *Groups and Symmetry*): Given subsets $X$ and $Y$ of a group $G$, if $X$ and $Y$ are both finite, $Y$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $XY\subseteq X$, then the size of $X$ is a multiple of the size of $Y$.

My idea is to use Lagrange's Theorem applied to the sets $X$ and $Y$, but that hinges on showing that $Y$ is a subgroup of $X$. I haven't been able to do that. Am I on the right track? Hints only please.

Comment: $XY$ will consist of various left cosets of $Y$, and hence, the number of elements in $XY$ is multiple of the number of elements in $Y$. Also, because $XY$ definitely contains $X$, it follows from the condition $XY\subseteq X$ that $XY = X$. Hence, the size of $X$ is a multiple of the size of $Y$.

Comment: @vnd I posted an "answer" using your advice, but I am not convinced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, $X\subseteq XY$ and we can state immediately that $X=XY$. Now either $X\subseteq Y$ or $Y\subset X$. In the first case we may conclude that $XY=Y$ and the orders of $X$ and $Y$ are equal. In the second case, $Y\subset X$, let $x_1\in X-Y$ and consider the set $x_1Y=\{x_1y:y\in Y\}$. Since $Y\rightarrow x_1Y:y\mapsto x_1y$ is a bijective map between finite sets, $|Y|=|x_1Y|$. Moreover, $Y\cap x_1Y=\varnothing$, for if $x\in Y\cap x_1Y$, then $x=x_1y=y’$ for some $y,y’\in Y$ and $x_1 = y’y^{-1}\in Y$, contradicting our assumption. So either $X= x_1Y \cup Y$ and $|X|= 2|Y|$ or there is some other element $x_2 \in X-(x_1Y\cup Y)$ such that $x_2Y\cap(x_1Y\cup Y) = \varnothing$ and $|x_2Y|=|Y|$ and $X=3|Y|$. We can only repeat this process so many times since $X$ is finite. So eventually we get $|X|=k|Y|$ for some positive integer $k$.

Comment: $X\subseteq XY$ and $XY \subseteq X$ together imply $X=XY$.

Comment: I understand, but why do I need that condition?

Comment: So that you can conclude $X=XY$.

Comment: But did I need that to show that the order of $X$ is a multiple of the order of $Y$?